# SQL Alchemy join association object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have to build a list of data from two tables. One regular table and another is association object table. Now I am doing something like this

```
items = User.query.all()
users_table = UsersTable(items)
```

and then using this with flask_table module like this:

```
class UsersTable(Table):
    classes = ['table', 'table-striped']
    id = Col('#')
    name = Col('Name')
```

How to write the query for *items* object that it could contain also field from AssocationClass? I mean that for example in AssocationClass I have field *user_type* and when I write like this:

```
class UsersTable(Table):
    classes = ['table', 'table-striped']
    id = Col('#')
    name = Col('Name')
    user_type = Col('Type')
```

This will work.

PS. I tried like this but this don't want to work.

```
items=User.query.join(AssocationClass, (AssocationClass.id_user == User.id)).all()
```

If it would be a normal SQL I would write something like this:

```
Select id, name, user_type from User join AssocationClass(id_user);
```

Comment: You should consider use [`relationship()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html) to declare the one-to-one relationship with the `AssociationClass` in `User` class. After the relationship got created, a simple `@property` returned `AssociationClass.user_type` can be added and help you get the `flask_table` work.

Comment: Yes, everything with `relationship()` is done, actually this is many to many relation. But in this problem I don't need to say about it. I changed in _UsersTable()_ like u said but now there is no data (but didn't get any error). Maybe the quary is bad?

Comment: The `@property` of `user_type` should be created in `User` class but not `UserTable`, and the returning value should be `self.[relationship-name].user_type`.

Comment: Thanks dude! Because of many relations in my db it was a little more complicated.